# dismiss UIAlertController presented by a modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I seem to be running into a problem similar to one in an unresolved posted question: [UIAlertController dismissing his presentingViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705319/uialertcontroller-dismissing-his-presentingviewcontroller)

I am presenting a modal view controller on top of a normal UIViewController. Then I'm popping up an alert on that modal view controller. When I push "ok" to dismiss the alert (generated with the code below), the modal view controller is also dismissed.

```
UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault 
                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action{ 
                                                    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];}];

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Sign up problem."
                                                               message:@"Some fields are empty. Please check your inputs and try again."
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction:ok];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can I dismiss just the alert?

I realize I can avoid this problem by using a navigation controller type setup instead and hiding the navigation bar, so I Get the same feel as the modal view controller, but this seems silly. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't call `self dismissViewController` in the button handler. That specifically states that you want the view controller dismissed.

You don't need to dismiss the alert. It will automatically dismiss itself. The only thing you should do in the button handler is perform whatever action you need. Do nothing if you don't need to do anything.

If your alert is simply a message and you don't need to perform any action, just do this:

```
UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated, and actually both behaviors are useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dismiss or remove the `UIAlertController` manually in any way in a button handler - it does that itself.

Just remove the call to `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.

Comment: But what if you actually want to for specific reasons. There must be a way to programmatically dismiss it. For example with the older ```UIAlertView``` you could dismiss/hide that programatically.

Comment: @Supertechnoboff: I think you can just `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]`. Not sure though.